# How to secure specific routes with token and filters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

**Context**

I'm doing an app (REST API) and I try to add some security.

**Current code**

So I created two methods :

```
public class Security {

    private final static String apiKey = "secretkey";

    // generate a token when data is created
    public static String generateToken(String dataid) {
        return Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(dataid)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .claim("roles", "user")
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, apiKey).compact();
    }


    // verify that user can access to data. He can access only if token is correct.
    public static ResponseEntity<?> checkToken(String id, ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        Optional<String> token = Optional.ofNullable(request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));

        if(token.isPresent() && token.get().startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String bearerToken = token.get().substring(7);
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(apiKey).parseClaimsJws(bearerToken);
            String dataid = claims.getBody().getSubject();
            if(dataid.equals(id))
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
            else
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**Objective**

But now my goal is to check if token is correct before routes which starts by `data/{id}` where `{id}` is same param as param of `checkToken(...)`.

**Idea(s)**

My first idea was to execute this code for each route which required security:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/data/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable("id") String id, ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) {
    ResponseEntity<?> checkToken = Security.checkToken(id, servletRequest, servletResponse);
    if(checkToken.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK)
        return checkToken;
    ...
}

@GetMapping(value = "/data/{id}/users")
public ResponseEntity<?> test(@PathVariable("id") String id, ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) {
    ResponseEntity<?> checkToken = Security.checkToken(id, servletRequest, servletResponse);
    if(checkToken.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK)
        return checkToken;
    ...
}

...
```

However, if my app has 100 routes, I will duplicate 100 times the code... Bad idea...

**Question**

There is a way to do it properly? With `Filter`? `Interceptor`? What is the best way?

Thanks for your help and advises.

NB : I hope I'm clear, if I'm not, ask me and will update my post.

Comment: If you're using Spring, this might help: https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security and (older) https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/

Comment: Are you using Spring Security?

Comment: @ngueno I try but I don't understand how it work with JWT... That's why I create a token for each resource and I check if token is correct but not automatically. My objective is to do this job automatically.